# How to formatting a column data in a table using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let's assume I have a CSV file named "Student.csv". The CSV file contains a header "EmergencyNum". I have loaded the CSV data into the student table using Python.I want to format the "EmergencyNum" column as follows,
If the Emergency number is 8 digit, I should load like xx-xxx-xxx (e.g. 67-890-876)
If the Emergency number is 9 digit, then I should load like xxx-xxx-xxx (e.g. 987-400-314)
How should I do this?

Example dataframe:

```
EmergencyNum DesiredColumn
67890876     67-890-876
987400314    987-400-314
```

Answer (score 3):

[f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) in Python are relatively new. It allows you to place variables in `{}` to directly inject them into strings.

e.g

```py
customer_name = "Ashley Williamson"

# print(f"")  # F-strings use f, followed by string.
print(f"Hello {customer_name}")
```

**Consider:**

```py
emer_number = 987654321  # Your input number
str_e = str(emer_number)  # Convert to string, for length, and direct indexing.

if len(str_e) == 8:
    print(f"{str_e[0:2]}-{str_e[2:5]}-{str_e[5:]}")  # xx-xxx-xxx
elif len(str_e) == 9:
    print(f"{str_e[0:3]}-{str_e[3:6]}-{str_e[6:]}")  # xxx-xxx-xxx
```

Comment: Use `==`, not `is`. They're entirely different beasts – it's mostly luck it works here.

Comment: f-string is supported in python versions >= 3.6 so I am not sure that the OP can adopt f-string based solution.

Comment: @balderman Absolutely agree. Presumed that OP has a relatively new project, and as such decided that >=3.6 would be most likely. Especially in the interest of promoting 3.x as standard. For <3.6 string concatenation would be the way to go, with a hit to readability.

Comment: No, for versions earlier than 3.6, you'd use `format`. String concatenation is usually not desirable for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['EmergencyNum'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:2]+'-'+x[2:5]+'-'+x[5:] if len(x) == 8 else x[:3]+'-'+x[3:6]+'-'+x[6:] )
```

**Output**

```
0     67-890-876
1    987-400-314
Name: EmergencyNum, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
def emergency_number_formatter(number):
    num_str = str(number)
    if len(num_str) == 8:
        return num_str[:2] + '-' + num_str[2:5] + '-' + num_str[5:]
    elif len(num_str) == 9:
        return num_str[:3] + '-' + num_str[3:6] + '-' + num_str[6:]
    else:
        raise Exception('Unsupported number: {}. Current len is {}'.format(num_str, len(num_str)))


print(emergency_number_formatter(987400314))
print(emergency_number_formatter(67890876))
```

output

```
987-400-314
67-890-876
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grouping option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-grouping-option) facilities. After `df=pandas.read_csv(....)` , EmergencyNum is int64.

Then

```
 df.EmergencyNum.apply(lambda num: format(num,"_").replace("_","-")) 
 0     67-890-876
 1    987-400-314
 Name: EmergencyNum, dtype: object
```

Answer (score -1):

1 . DEFINE FUNCTON WITH PARAMETER python

```
def nu_format(n):
return format(int(n[:-1]), ",").replace(",", "-") + n[-1]
```

2. CALL THE FUNCTION python

nu_format(67890876)

try by using above code

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question?